# create an edittext and get its data in another gui matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I want to get a number in a gui (say N), and create N "edittext" in another gui figure when pushing a "pushbutton". I write this code to do so (which works correctly):

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
input_num = str2double(get(handles.edit1,'String'));
edittext = zeros(input_num,1);
panel= uipanel('parent',untitled1,...
'Title','Input Data',... 
'position',[.01 .05 .25 .95]); 
for i = 1:input_num
  edittext(i,1) = uicontrol('parent',panel,'style','edit',...
      'string','',...
      'position',[20 360-i*25 40 20]);
end
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

then in the second gui, I want to get the data which are entered by user in the created "edittext"s  and use them to do something.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using the `Tag` properties of the figures and `uipanel` you are creating to fetch the appropriate element from the 1st GUI in the 2nd GUI.

Here is a commented example:

Let's create GUI1 with the original tag 'GUI1'. Notice that we also add a tag to the uipanel...and that we use `k` as the loop variable instead of `i`.

```
function MakeEditTextsGUI

hFig1 = figure('Name','Fig1','Tag','GUI1');
input_num = 3;
edittext = zeros(input_num,1);
panel= uipanel('parent',hFig1,'Tag','Panel1',...
    'Title','Input Data',...
    'position',[.01 .05 .25 .95]);
for k = 1:input_num
    edittext(k,1) = uicontrol('parent',panel,'style','edit',...
        'string','','position',[20 360-k*25 40 20],'Tag',sprintf('edit_%i',k));
end

end
```

This is the figure in which the user enters the data.

Let's create a 2nd GUI with a pushbutton that the user pushes to fetch the data from the 1st GUI, which must be opened:

```
function GetEditBoxes

hFig2 = figure('Position',[400 400 200 100],'Tag','GUI2');

hButton = uicontrol('Style','push','Position',[60 60 80 20],'String','Get content','Callback',@(s,e) GetContent);

    function GetContent

        %// Fetch figure 1
        hCurrFig = findobj('Tag','GUI1');

        %// Make current figure
        figure(hCurrFig);

        %// Fetch Panel1
        hCurrPanel = findobj('Tag','Panel1');

        %// Get its children and order from first to last
        EditBoxes = flipud(get(hCurrPanel,'Children'));

        %// Get number of edit boxes
        NumBoxes = numel(EditBoxes);

        %// Go and get the data!
        for p = 1:NumBoxes           
           get(EditBoxes(p),'String')
        end
    end
end
```

I did not include any error catching code but its easy to verify if every edit box contains an entry. Once the user presses the button, the content of each box is displayed in the command window but you can easily store them into an array or something.

Have fun!